# Jquery - match link color to image displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ive got a slider with 3 circles at the bottom, when picture is displayed, the correct circle background must be turned to green, correlating to the correct image. Ive got it working, but when user clicks on a new circle, to change image, the old background color remains in place and does not disappear, as you can see from the picture example.

[image]

In the above example, the page loaded with the middel image highlighted, when user clicked the right circle the image changed, and highlighted the right circle (as it should) BUT the middle buttons highlight color remained in place...What am I missing here? Code follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
      $("iLink").removeClass()
        $(this).addClass("over")  
    }) ; 
});

.over {
    background:#008000;
}

<a href="#" id="l1" class="iLink1"  onclick="imgSliderL1()"><img id="i1" src="images/dot.png"/></a>
     <a href="#" id="l2" class="iLink2" onclick="imgSliderL2()"><img id="i2" src="images/dot.png" /></a>
     <a href="#" id="l3" class="iLink3" onclick="imgSliderL3()"><img id="i3" src="images/dot.png" /></a>
```

Comment: just for your information: [in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) when you request a class name, you need to use the `.` (dot) before the name. This `$("iLink")` should be `$(".iLink")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is `iLink`?

```
$("iLink").removeClass()
```

change to

```
 $('a').removeClass()
```

why need different class?

Answer (score 0):

select that id and associate condition which one id is going to be selected than use css property of jquery or css function.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("iLink").removeClass()
```

to

```
$("a[class^='iLink']").removeClass()
```

because the a tags contains different classes but they all start with same name iLink